# Extract method from class

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a class GamePanel with method update(). How to extract that method into separate file (class)?

```
public class MainThread{ 
   GamePanel gamePanel;

   public MainThread(GamePanel gamePanel){
      this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
    } 
  
   void run (){
      gamePanel.update();
   }
}

public class GamePanel {
   private int move = 0;

   void update (){
      move ++;
   }

   void calculate (){
      if (move > 5)
         move = 0;
   }
}
```

I tried to make a class Update:

```
public class Update{
   private GamePanel gamePanel;

   void update (){
      gamePanel.move ++;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking. Your question looks like you already have the answer: you ask *"how to extract that method into separate file"* and you created a class with the `update()` method in a separate class.

Comment: not sure if that is a good idea, basically breaking encapsulation, one of the important features of Object Oriented Programing paradigm

Comment: Probably I found the solution - needed to change method update in Class Update to static with parameter GamePanel and call it from method in GamePanel: Update.update(this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that GamePanel.move is a private variable, so you cannot access it from the Update class. You can make this variable `public` and your class will work.

Otherwise, if you don't want to make it public you can make it `protected` and make Update extend GamePanel, so that the only the subclass has access to the variable

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had also to change modifiers to protected too, thanks.

Comment: You're wellcome. If this fixed your problem, pleae mark my answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

```
//method update in GamePanel should be like this:
protected int move = 0;

public void update() {
        Update.update(this);
}

//Class Update:

public class Update{
   
   public static void update(GamePanel gamePanel) {
      gamePanel.move ++;
   }
}
```